# Is there a free LOCAL "translation blackbox"?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, translation

I'm trying to gain the ability to translate any given string in English, into a bunch of other major languages. Or vice versa.

It is completely unacceptable for my data to ever leave my computer, so language translation "APIs" are useless to me.

In other words, it has to be a translator.exe binary which simply takes an input string and spits out the translation on the command line, using whatever free dictionaries exist and which are all packed into the program and doesn't require any further "setup" by me.

Is there really no such thing? It would be extremely useful as it's simply not acceptable to have private strings travel over the network and trust the translation entity with that data. Plus those APIs will want you to pay money for anything but "free tier"/demo usage.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! What budget have you planned for that? And I mean price as well as disk space, as for that concept you'd need a bunch of dictionaries local as well (I've no idea how big they'd get or how they're structured for good translations which are not just word-by-word, but this *might* be an issue). Further, can you **[edit]** your question and specify the "bunch of other major languages" that **must** be supported? The only one you've mentioned explicitly is English. Thanks!